# System.Net.Http missed from project after installation of .net standard 2 nuget package

Tags: nuget, .net-4.6.1, .net-standard-2.0

I created **.net framework 4.6.1**. project, it has GAC refernce **System.Net.Http** which uses *C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Net.Http.dll*. Then I installed **.net standard 2** nuget package and after project reloading I see this:
[image]

At the same time project builds ok. How to fix it? Versions of tools: **Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.3.5, Nuget 4.3.1**

Comment: It works fine on my side. What`s the path of this reference in the properties windows? If this issue persist, could you please give me some detail steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT path and other properties are empty. Actually I described all steps. I'll try to investigate deeply.

Comment: since I could not reproduce this issue, I guess if there is any difference between you and I. So I ask more detail. What`s the version of your Visual Studio and nuget?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.3.5, Nuget 4.3.1

Comment: @Leo-MSFT my problem looks like this https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/484

Comment: Looks like it's an open issue for .net-standard for now. Finally I added target for net461 to .net-standard project and update package. Now it looks fine.

Comment: yes, it is still a open issue. You can convert your workaround in the comment to the answer, and mark it, so it is benefit for other communities who has the same issue. Thanks.